# Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath error in Url.Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error : Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath. I am simply trying to display an image using "Url.Content" in the Index view. Upon entering this page in debug, it breaks with above mentioned error: Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Controller:

```
// GET: Customers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,DiscountLevelID,LoyaltyLevelID,CustomerCompanyName,CustomerName,CustomerSurname,CustomerGUID,CustomerStatus,CustomerAddress,CustomerTel,CustomerCel,CustomerNumber,CustomerContact,CustomerLogo,CustomerLogoPath,LastStoreCustomerSyncID")] Customer customer, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(physicalPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalPath);
            string physicalFullPath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, ImageName);
            file.SaveAs(physicalFullPath);

            customer.CustomerLogo = ImageName;
            customer.CustomerLogoPath = physicalFullPath;
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

Index cshtml

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create","Customers")" class="btn btn-primary">Add Company</a>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Customer Surname</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>CustomerLogo</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.CustomerCompanyName</td>
                        <td>@item.CustomerName</td>
                        <td>@item.CustomerSurname</td>
                        <td>@item.CustomerAddress</td>
                        <td><img src="~/Images/@Url.Content(@item.CustomerLogoPath)" width="100" height="100" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Customers", new {id = item.CustomerID} )" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> Edit</a>                            </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Comment: `CustomerLogoPath` is `null` in at least one of your objects - although since  your code is setting `CustomerLogoPath = "~/Images/YourImageName` then `src="~/Images/@Url.Content(@item.CustomerLogoPath)"` would be generating `src="~/Images/Images/YourImageName"` (do you really have an `Images` subfolder inside your `Images` folder?

Comment: No I dont have an Images subfolder, Images is the main folder

Comment: @StephenMuecke How would I resolve this?

Comment: The I assume you probably want just `src="@Url.Content(@item.CustomerLogoPath)"`. But that is not the source of the error your getting. It suggests that `CustomerLogoPath` is `null` in at least one of the items in your collection- have you set it in the GET method?

Comment: public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
Thats my GetMethod , what would I need to set here ? Thanks for your help @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've updated my original post to include both the GET and POST method

Comment: Its the GET method for `Index()` that you need to show

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Blone moment lol, here is the code for the Index:  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Customers.ToList());
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152999/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-unicorn-girl).